# Stop rerendering on every scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, sapui5, dom-events

I have created a tree table with one `sap.ui.core.Control` written which renders a new control for every row when the page is loaded.

After the page is completely loaded everything works fine but as soon as I scroll the renderer is hit again and the rows are rendered again and again.

Because of the re rendering of rows on every scroll the UI is distorted and click functions on the table components do not work properly

I have tried capturing the JS mouse scroll event but it doesn't work.

```
var Cc = sap.ui.Control {
  renderer :
    render : function (){
     // Need a check here if it's getting hit on scroll
     // renders for every row
  }
}
```